# Extract domain and subdomains in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to extract domains, subdomains and subsubomains from a link.
Example `https://stackoverflow.com/users/17141604/badinmaths`

domain : https://stackoverflow.com/

subdomain : https://stackoverflow.com/users

subsubdomain : https://stackoverflow.com/users/17141604  (even if the subsubdomain is weird)

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

domain : https://stackoverflow.com/

subdomain : https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Here : no subsubdomain

I already know how to extract domain with NET.HOST but I need to extract other parts.
I have a large number of URL where I have to apply this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be better way but you can consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/17141604/badinmaths' url
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask' 
)
SELECT domain,
       domain || paths[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS subdomain,
       domain || paths[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] || '/' || paths[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS subsubdomain
  FROM sample_table,
UNNEST ([STRUCT(SPLIT(url, NET.HOST(url)) AS split_url)]),
UNNEST ([STRUCT(split_url[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] || NET.HOST(url) || '/' AS domain)]),
UNNEST ([STRUCT(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(split_url[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], r'(\w+)\/') AS paths)]);
```

**Query results**

[image]

- `UNNEST ([STRUCT(*expression* AS *field_name*)])`

  - with this trick, you can treat *field_name* as *column_name* of base table.
  - useful to reduce the repetition of same *expression* in the select list
- `SPLIT(url, NET.HOST(url))` returns an array of **['https', '/questions/ask']** which will be used later to reconstruct *domain* and *subdomain*s.
- For the regular expression, see here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PqdraX/2)